# why i get an error in the date formatter code?

Tags: ios, swift

I’m trying to convert my AM PM time pickers to 24h format to print the start and end time to calculate the price but i got an unknown error. attached is photo of my UI to simplify the idea and my code.
Note: the end time is automatically shows after i choose the start time
[image: My UI]

```
@objc func donePressed(){
  // formatter
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateStyle = .none
  formatter.timeStyle = .short
           
  startTimeTxt.text = formatter.string(from: StartTimePicker.date)
  self.view.endEditing(true)
           
  endTimeTxt.text = formatter.string(from: EndTimePicker.date)
  self.view.endEditing(true)
        
  let starttimecal = StartTimeTxt.text!
  let endtimecal = EndTimeTxt.text!
        
  let StartTo24 = starttimecal
  let EndTo24 = endtimecal
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

  let sTime = dateFormatter.date(from: startTo24)
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
  let sTime24 = dateFormatter.string(from: sTime!)
  print("24 hour formatted Date:", sTime24)
  let eTime = dateFormatter.date(from: endTo24)
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
  let eTime24 = dateFormatter.string(from: eTime!) // here the fatal error comes after i choose the start time from simulator 
  print("24 hour formatted Date:", eTime24)
}
```

Comment: variable names should begin with a lowercase letter. It's very confusing to read code that doesn't follow convention. Stime should be sTime. Etc...

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Why are you doing this, you go from Date to String then back to Date and then to String again? Why not go from Date to String 24h and from the same Date to String 12h if you need both formats? And is it really a String you want if you want to perform calculations?

Comment: how can i do this? sorry I’m a beginner

Comment: I’m trying to take the time in 24h format to subtract the end time from the start time and *15 to calculate price. this is why im doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 12h time format to display in the text fields you can use the formatter you already have but I also like to set the locale

```
let dateFormatter12h = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter12h.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter12h.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
```

To calculate the time difference there is a function for that in the `Calendar` class, here we calculate the number of hours and minutes between two dates (this is an assumption since I don't know exactly what calculation you want to do)

```
let hourAndMinutes = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startDate, to: endDate)
```

Below is a more complete example

```
//Sample data
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(3.25*60*60) //add 3h and 15 minutes

// Format and print in 12h format
let dateFormatter12h = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter12h.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter12h.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
let start = dateFormatter12h.string(from: startDate)
let end = dateFormatter12h.string(from: endDate)
print(start, end)

// Calculate time difference in hours and minutes
let hourAndMinutes = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startDate, to: endDate)
print(hourAndMinutes)

// Calculate price, the formula is just an example
let price = hourAndMinutes.hour! * 15 + hourAndMinutes.minute! * 15 / 60
print(price)
```

Output

> 6:46 PM 10:01 PM
> hour: 3 minute: 15 isLeapMonth: false
> 48

Comment: thank you!! it worked but i have a problem when i change the values it print the first value only. why to make it print the values every time i change?

Comment: I don't think I understand, what value are you talking about? And are you sure this is relevant to your current question and not another issue?

Comment: Yes. I copied your code and it works. The problem is: it print the first values i put in the UITextFields for the start and end time. when i change them to another time, it print the old calculation for the old start and end time.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it or add print statements to see if the dates are updated, the price is recalculated etc?

Comment: yes the problem is it does not change the values of startDate and endDate when i change them from the time pickers, but when i print the UITextFields where the pickers are stored in it change every time